# How to decide between two difficult career choices?

Tags: software-industry

I'm a software engineer currently living in a foreign country. Recently I got two job offers one from OrgA, in my country and another one from OrgB, Europe. While initially, I was sure that I want to join OrgA, the offer that I got from OrgB is amazing. I am getting ~2x more money from OrgB. Including cost-of-living, savings are ~1.5x more in Europe.

**I'm stuck**, on one hand, OrgA seems like a good choice to work with technologies, grow in the corporate world on others at OrgB there is a decent chance to learn and their package is so good that I'm having trouble coming to a final decision.

Has anyone faced a choice like this where you have to decide between two good choices, how do you decide?

Comment: Downvoting is OK! But it would be great if downvoters can also point out what is wrong and how to improve?

Comment: Workplace don't do career choices. There are too many personal factors on these (and very few we can address)

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but I honestly don't know how to approach such question. An obvious thing is to have all important factors listed, along with their weight, and then compare those two offers in terms of their weighted benefits. The weights, however, will vary a lot! They are definitely something you should define yourself. And there could be so many factors (some of them beyond the scope of the question here, like family/friends/culture) that I don't even know where to start listing them... No one but you knows what's important for you.

Comment: "Is having a bigname corp better than good money now?" Think of it this way : how much would you want to pay for a bigname corp ? Also, in my book, Booking.com certainly don't sound ridiculous. But there are too many things at stake here. For example I made my own choice to stay in France knowing perfectly there are positions abroad where I could earn 2 or 3 times more, because I value staying close to my roots more than money.

Comment: _"How do you decide?"_ isn't a specific choice, and it's a situation that a lot of people face. I've removed some text that may have distracted people from that, please feel free to revert my edit if you disagree @user323

Answer (score 5):

Jobs can come and go, but the reason you work is standard of living.

I always follow the money because I can do interesting things in my spare time, but I can't print money without risking serious jail time.

Comment: Cost of living is also a factor to consider...

Comment: perhaps, perhaps not, thats a gamble I wouldn't take. What is a fact though is if you're making X amount and being headhunted in the future, they'll offer more than X amount.... so simple equation is the higher X is the better.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I've never traveled to either place, but I would also consider the cost of living. Is the cost of living in Amsterdam higher than that in Cape Town? I would guess so but I have no idea, you live there. The 2x salary is a big thing to drive your decision but compare to cost of living. Other than that, while I agree AWS is a better name than Booking.com, Booking.com is also a big name and I don't think AWS is worth a 50% salary decrease.

Also since you're an expat, another factor to consider is how much you want to see your family and where they live. If they're in the US, Amsterdam is better than being all the way on the other side of the world. If your family is in Europe already, maybe the difference isn't as meaningful.